# how to implement Flask-Dance with Flask Blueprints

Tags: python, flask, flask-dance

I tried to use Flask-Dance with normal flask app and it works and if I try to implement with flask blueprints it doesn't work. How to register flask-dance to flask blueprints?

My views.py for auth blueprint

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, redirect, current_app, request
from app.auth import auth
from flask_dance.contrib import github

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
return render_template('auth/login.html')

@auth.route("/")
def github():
    if not github.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("github.login"))
    resp = github.get("/user")
    assert resp.ok
    return "You are @{login} on GitHub".format(login=resp.json()["login"])
```

my **init**.py for auth blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_dance.contrib.github import make_github_blueprint, github

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

blueprint = make_github_blueprint(client_id="m-client-id",client_secret="my-client-secret")

auth.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/auth")



from app.auth import views
```

and my main **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_fontawesome import FontAwesome

from app.config import Config

fa = FontAwesome()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    fa.init_app(app)
    
    from app.public import public
    app.register_blueprint(public)
    
    from app.auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth)
    
    return app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should create and register different blueprint for github.

github/**init**.py

```
from flask_dance.contrib import github
from flask_dance.contrib.github import make_github_blueprint

github_blueprint = make_github_blueprint(client_id='your-client-id',client_secret='your-client-secret')



from app.github import views
```

github/views.py

```
@github_blueprint.route("/")
def github_login():
     if not github.authorized:
          return redirect(url_for('github.login'))
     account_info = github.get('/user')
     if account_info.ok:
          account = account_info.json()
          return '<h1>Your Github name is {}'.format(account['login'])
```

and finally in your main **init**.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_fontawesome import FontAwesome

from app.config import Config

fa = FontAwesome()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
      app = Flask(__name__)
      app.config.from_object(Config)
      fa.init_app(app)

      from app.public import public
      app.register_blueprint(public)

      from app.auth import auth
      app.register_blueprint(auth)

      from app.github import github_blueprint
      app.register_blueprint(github_blueprint,  url_prefix='/github_login')
      #/github_login=callback url

      return app
```

Comment: How will you access @github_blueprint in github/view.py? That variable is declared in a different file.